# Column index error when adding NumericUpDownColumn

Tags: c#, datagridview, numericupdown

I have 2 forms (`form1` & `form2`). The `DataGridView` is on `form1`, and data retrieved from `form2`. And the `DataSource` is a `List` that I defined. Now in `form2`, I assigned data to `List1 resultItems`; the code is below.

```
form1.DataGridview .DataSource = null;  
form1.DataGridview .Refresh();
form1.DataGridview .Columns.Clear();
form1.DataGridview .AutoGenerateColumns = true; 
form1.DataGridview .DataSource = resultItems;
```

Because I would like the `DataGridView` to have a `NumericUpDownColumn`, I used the code to add it. But the problem is that I insert this `NumericUpDownColumn` to the `DataGridView` as column 2, but when I navigate back to `form1`, my `NumericUpDownColumn` became column 0. I don't know why the column is not at index 2.

In fact, I would like the column `value` to became a `NumericUpDownColumn`. But I don't know how to change it to a `NumericUpDownColumn`. So I insert a `NumericUpDownColumn`, and column `value` is set invisible.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygbLo.png]

```
 NumericUpDownColumn num = new NumericUpDownColumn();
 num.HeaderText = "ValueNum";
 num.Name = "num";
 num.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
 form1.DataGridview.Columns.Insert(2, num);          
 form1.DataGridview.Columns[3].Visible = false;


 //--------------------------------------------
 class List1
 {
     public string Index{ get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Value { get; set; }
     public string Index2 { get; set; }
     public string Name2 { get; set; }
     public string Value2 { get; set; }

     public ColumnNamesPdoClone(
         string Index,
         string Name,
         string Value,
         string Index2,
         string Name2,
         string Value2
         )
     {
         this.Index= Index;
         this.Name = Name;
         this.Value = Value;
         this.Index2 = Index2;
         this.Name2 = Nam2e;
         this.Value2 = Value2;
     }
 }
```

Comment: You are clearing columns of DataGridView before setting its data source. You are also adding column to it at position 2. Which on of these codes executed first? When you add column to DataGridView does it already have some columns? Why can't you add columns to DataGridView at design time in whatever order and type you want and in code just bind it to the proper data set?

Comment: 1st: I bound datagridview datasource is list resultItems.  
       So datagridview have 6 column .
2nd: I insert a NumericUpDownColumn in datagridview column[2]
But in fact, this NumericUpDownColumn is in column[0].